# How do I receive XML file via POST in django

Tags: django

I'm trying to send XML file to django view using requests. I think the file is being sent by doing:

```
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/xml'}
response = requests.post('http://localhost:8000/file/', data=file, headers=headers)
```

in view I have:

```
class ReceiveFile(TemplateView):
    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print request.read()
        return HttpResponse('')
```

So how do I read file here in view and save it as xml again? request.read() gives me path from where file was sent.

Best, Blake

Comment: Try [`request.body`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.body)

Comment: You shouldn't be doing that in `dispatch`, but in `post`.

Comment: request.body is giving me the same output as request.read() which is the path to a file from where the file was sent

Comment: In that case, it looks like the request is sending the file name, not the contents.

Answer (score 2):

You are sending the file path, rather than the contents of the file.

You will need to send the contents of the file instead.

Assuming that your file contains valid XML:

```
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/xml'}
open_file = open(file,'r')
file_contents = open_file.read()
response = requests.post('http://localhost:8000/file/', data=file_contents, headers=headers)
```